# Best MongoDB schema for twitter clone?

Tags: twitter, mongodb, node.js, schema, mongoose

I know similar questions have been asked, but looking for a very basic answer to a basic question.  I am new to MongoDB and making a twitter style app (blogs, followers, etc) and I'm wondering the best schema to use.

Right now I have (on a very high level):

```
Member {
  login: string,
  pass: string,
  posts: [
    {
      title: string,
      blog: string,
      comments: [ { comment: string } ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There is more to it, but that gives you the idea.  **Now the problem is I'm looking to add the "follow" feature and I'm not sure the best route to go.**

I could add a "following" embedded doc to the Member, but I'm just not sure using mongoDB what the smartest method would be.  My main concearn would obviously be the main "feed" page where you see all of the people you are following's posts.

Answer (score 11):

This is not an ideal schema for a Twitter clone. The main problem is that "posts" is an evergrowing array which means mongo will have to move your massive document every few posts because it ran out of document padding. Additionally there's a hard (16mb) size limit to documents which makes this schema restrictive at best.

The ideal schema depends on whether or not you expect Twitter's load. The "perfect" mongodb schema in terms of maintainability and easy of use is not the same as the one I'd use for something with Twitter's throughput. For example, in the former case I'd use a posts collection with a document per post. In the high throughput scenario I'd start making bucket documents for small groups of posts (say, one per "get more" page). Additionally in the high throughput scenario you'd have to keep the follower's timeline up to date in seperate user timeline documents while in low throughput scenarios you can simply query them.

Comment: Good point, @Remon, but the OP's question was not about the "posts" array. He/she did mention that this is a simplified version of the schema, and the question is about how to implement following.

Comment: Thanks @Remon this is great information.  The site will never need to scale to the level Twitter does, but it is not for a small site either.  It will have to be able to scale, but nothing crazy.

And like @Martin Vilcans mentioned, any input on the "following" aspect would be great.  But the information you provided already helps.  I think I'm afraid of making it to relational so I might be over compensating.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the original question. Following should be implemented by an embedded array as suggested since it'll be relatively hard to hit a 16mb limit with just an array of UUIDs. If you plan to stick a lot of other data in your users collection you could put the followes array in dedicated per-user documents. Then, upon a user posting a new post you asynchronously (use a message queue in a workload queue/consumer model) to iterate over that array and update the timelines of all followers. This allows for near endless scaling and is close to the current Twitter architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This question is the same the one how widely used in the blog post example and how to model blog posts and comments. You just have to apply the same concepts here. You have the following options:

- embedded documents
- dedicated collections and performing multiple queries

The pros and cons have been widely discussed. Embedded docs can only be 16MB large and it is not possible to return individual parts of an matched array in MongoDB...make your choice.

Not going any further because as said: the same question has been discussed in numerous questions about "schema design". Just google "Schema Design MongoDB" or look for the same on SO.

Comment: Simple blogs or tweets I get but are in no way the same as what I am asking.  My only question is on adding the "follow" feature. What I am looking for is someone with more experiences opinion on the best way to set it up.

For the "follow" feature, I either need to list in the members doc all the people they are following, or I could put instead all of the people following them, etc.  The twitter clones I have seen all just deal with adding a "tweet" or blog.  None of them touch on the tougher issue of setting up the "follow".

Comment: You are not able to abstract given solutions to your problem from the data model point of view. Handling relations of what every nature are done in MongoDB either through dedicated collections or embedded documents. Every documentation is explaining this. Please apply it to your problem

Comment: Although I don't agree that a twitter schema will resemble a blog schema that closely the general topic has been discussed widely so a few googles here and there should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "following" array to the Member document should work well. It should contain the user IDs of the people that member is following. Your code will have to retrieve the list and construct a query that retrieves the tweets of those users. As Mongo is nonrelational,  there's no way to construct a query that joins the Member and Tweet collections and does this in a single query, but you should be able to reduce network overhead by doing this on the database server, using server-side code execution: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution.

Comment: Both server-side code execution and potentially large, ever growing embedded arrays should be used sparingly in production environments where load is expected to be considerable.

Comment: You seem to have given this more thought than me, @Remon. The bit about ever-growing arrays makes sense, but I don't see how server-side code execution would be worse than two round-trips to the server.

Comment: It's less than obvious but it's due to the fact that the JS engine within mongo is single threaded and thus cannot take advantage of all available cpu resources. Even map/reduce currently suffer from this (which is odd since it was basically invented with parallelism in mind). If that server-side script is used more often than a single core can process it'll start slowing down the entire server. So yes, in quite a few cases two round trips is actually faster, or at least easier to scale up ;) As with everything though, test and see what works best.