# Store data related to separated stream

Tags: mongodb, twitter, twitter4j

I'm going to get tweet about several topics using filter/track method, twitter4J/Java language. In addition, I use MongoDB to store them, but i wonder if there is a way to store tweets related to those topics in separated databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to store them in different databases? I believe that different collections would be sufficient. Storing tweets in MongoDB was discussed at [Twitter 101: Store Tweets with MongoDB](http://learnmongo.com/posts/mongodb-php-twitter-part-1/) and I think you'll find it relevant.

MongoDB schema for Twitter-type projects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881974/how-do-i-design-a-mongodb-schema-for-a-twitter-article-aggregator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515686/best-mongodb-schema-for-twitter-clone).

There's very good information on schema design with MongoDB [here|http://www.ticketmaster.ie/The-Phantom-of-the-Opera-tickets/artist/804174].

Comment: Ah, exactly i want to store them in different COLLECTIONS. I'll spend time read these links. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah since i'm new at stackoverflow, i'm not allowed to vote up. But it's nice to you. I'll vote it up asap.

Answer (score 0):

if you're storing graph related information, check out neo4j and orientDB (or perhaps flockDB if it meets your criteria).

Comment: the main point in my process is to crawl tweets about several tracking filters: both keywords and locations and then use mongoDB to store them to their own databases. after all i may graph them so i'll have a look at your suggestion.